# Correlation with a non significant difference score

Tags: correlation, t-test

I have a doubt on a correlation.
I have a research with two hypothesis, the first is studied with a t-test, which is not significant. The second is studied with a correlation, where I need to correlate the difference scores from the first hypothesis with another variable. In the results on the second hypothesis, there is a significant correlation. However, this correlation is between the variable and a difference score that is not significant (according to H1 testing). My doubt is, does it make sense to study the correlation even if the different score is not significant?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If I understand the question:  Yes, it makes sense.  Unless you intend to conduct one hypothesis test only based on the results of the other hypothesis test.

Comment: Thank you! 
Basically to clarify the question:

Comment: Basically to clarify the question: I had different pre/post test scores and I studied if the different was significant with a t-test. Then, I correlated those differences with another variable, but one of the differences was not significant. However, the correlation between the not significant different and the variable is significant. Can I actually do this and interpret that significant correlation?

Comment: Same response.  There's no reason why you would make conducting one hypothesis test dependent on the results of another hypothesis test, unless you had a reason to do so.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with any of this. However, to me (before morning coffee), this question still seems unresolved. If you can edit your question to give a more detailed description of your data, what you are testing, and why, maybe someone can give a better-targeted or more complete answer.

Comment: The study regards the effects of peer-to-peer environmental workshops in raising pro-environmental social identity among youth. Therefore we hypothesize that strenght of social identification with youth and pro-environmental social norms increase after the workshop compared to before (H1). We found that norms increased, but strength in Social identification didn’t. We also hypothesized that the effectiveness of the workshop would depend how much the peer trainer was perceived as identity leader (how much the leader is representative of the group) (H2).

Comment: In other words, we hypothesized that the more the peer leader was perceived as an identity leader, the more the workshop would have been effective in enhancing strenght of social identification with youth and pro-environmental social norms.” (H2).

Comment: With the t-test for H1 we found that norms increased, while strenght of social identification didn’t. Then, to test hypothesis two, I correlated the difference scores with identity leadership to see if indeed the more the trainer was perceived as identity leader, the more the effectiveness in raising social identification and norms. However, while norms increased significantly, strenght of social identification didn’t. So here is my doubt, whether it actually makes sense to study this correlation or if it is meaningless regardless because the increase in strength is not significant anyways.